# Change Quote Owner As Opportunity Owner for a Particular Profile

Tags: apex, before-trigger

I have written an Apex class for changing the Quote owner as the Opportunity owner for Profile named 'TriLink Sales & Service'. I have called this class class in Trigger. But it is throwing 'Apex trigger changeOwner caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: changeOwner: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Class.changeOwnerClass.changeOwner: line 7, column 1' error.

**APEX CODE:**

public class changeOwnerClass{

```
public list<Opportunity> lstOpp ;
public void changeOwner(list<Quote> lstQuote){
    Profile p = [select id,Name from Profile where id=:Userinfo.getProfileid()];
    System.debug(p);
    for (Opportunity opp : lstOpp){
        for(Quote objQuote : lstQuote){
        if(p.Name == 'TriLink Sales & Service' || p.Name!= 'TriLink GMP'){
            objQuote.OwnerId = opp.OwnerId;
            System.debug(opp.OwnerId);
            System.debug(objQuote.OwnerId);
        }}
    }
}
```

}

**TRIGGER:**

trigger changeOwner on Quote (before insert) {
changeOwnerClass clsChangeOwner  = new changeOwnerClass ();

if(trigger.isInsert && trigger.isBefore){
clsChangeOwner.changeOwner(trigger.new);
}
}

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: where do you set the lstOpp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code and it is working now.

**APEX CODE:**

public class changeOwnerClass{
public static void changeOwner(list lstQuote){
List oppIds = new List();
for (Quote quote: lstQuote) {
oppIds.add(quote.OpportunityId);
}

```
    Map<Id,Opportunity> OppMap = new Map<Id,Opportunity>([Select id, ownerId from Opportunity where id in :oppIds]);
    Profile p = [select id,Name from Profile where id=:Userinfo.getProfileid()];
    for(Quote quote : lstQuote){
        if(p.Name == 'TriLink Sales & Service'){
            quote.OwnerId = oppMap.get(quote.OpportunityId).OwnerId;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**TRIGGER:**

trigger changeOwner on Quote (before insert) {
if(trigger.isInsert && trigger.isBefore)
{
changeOwnerClass.changeOwner(trigger.new);
}
}

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to make the Quote Owner to be the Opportunity CreatedBy.Name as the owner?

Answer (score 0):

```
public list<Opportunity> lstOpp ;
public void changeOwner(list<Quote> lstQuote){
    Profile[] p = [select id,Name from Profile where id=:Userinfo.getProfileid()];
    System.debug(p);
if(!lstOpp.isEmpty()){
    for (Opportunity opp : lstOpp){
        for(Quote objQuote : lstQuote){
      
        if(!p.isEmpty() && (p[0].Name == 'TriLink Sales & Service' || p[0].Name!= 'TriLink GMP')){
            objQuote.OwnerId = opp.OwnerId;
            System.debug(opp.OwnerId);
            System.debug(objQuote.OwnerId);
        }}
    }
}
}
```